Angular Standalone Component Unit Tests using Spectator: NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient
I am trying to test a component, which has a service in its dependencies. That service, BanknotesAndCoinsService, has a so-called 'client-service'  as its dependency, BanknotsAndCoinsClientService, whose responsibility is to make back end calls. It uses HttpClient.
In tests I have mocked both services. However, I still get an error that suggests that the tests try to instantiate these services instead of their mocks.
Angular version: 18.2.0.
For testing I do use: JEST + ngneat/spectator.
Error:
CirculationColumnChartsComponent › testName

    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[CirculationColumnChartsComponent])[BanknotesAndCoinsService -> BanknotesAndCoinsService -> BanknotesAndCoinsClientService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!

      10 | })
      11 | export class BanknotesAndCoinsClientService {
    > 12 |   private http = inject(HttpClient);
         |                        ^
      13 |
      14 |   moneyCirculationData$ = this.http.get<CirculationData[]>('http://localhost:3000/banknotes_and_coins').pipe(
      15 |     // delay(500), // this is simulation of loading time of http request

      at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1659:27)
      at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3105:33)
      at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3105:33)
      at injectInjectorOnly (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1106:40)
      at ɵɵinject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1112:42)
      at inject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1198:12)
      at new BanknotesAndCoinsClientService (src/app/banknotes-and-coins/data-access/banknotes-and-coins.client.service.ts:12:24)
      at Object.BanknotesAndCoinsClientService_Factory [as factory] (ng:/BanknotesAndCoinsClientService/ɵfac.js:5:10)
      at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3233:47
      at runInInjectorProfilerContext (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:871:9)
      at R3Injector.hydrate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3232:21)
      at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3095:33)
      at injectInjectorOnly (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1106:40)
      at ɵɵinject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1112:42)
      at inject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1198:12)
      at new BanknotesAndCoinsService (src/app/banknotes-and-coins/data-access/banknotes-and-coins.service.ts:26:50)
      at Object.BanknotesAndCoinsService_Factory [as factory] (ng:/BanknotesAndCoinsService/ɵfac.js:5:10)
      at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3233:47
      at runInInjectorProfilerContext (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:871:9)
      at R3Injector.hydrate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3232:21)
      at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3095:33)
      at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3105:33)
      at ChainedInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5447:36)
      at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5800:39)
      at getOrCreateInjectable (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5848:12)
      at ɵɵdirectiveInject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11936:19)
      at NodeInjectorFactory.CirculationColumnChartsComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:/CirculationColumnChartsComponent/ɵfac.js:6:7)
      at getNodeInjectable (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6060:44)
      at createRootComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:16919:35)
      at ComponentFactory.create (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:16770:29)
      at initComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:2039:51)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:416:32)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:2176:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:415:38)
      at Object.onInvoke (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:7241:33)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:415:38)
      at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
      at NgZone.run (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:7087:28)
      at _TestBedImpl.createComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:2051:41)
      at Function.createComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:1842:37)
      at createSpectator (node_modules/@ngneat/spectator/fesm2022/ngneat-spectator.mjs:1590:29)
      at node_modules/@ngneat/spectator/fesm2022/ngneat-spectator.mjs:1582:27
      at src/app/banknotes-and-coins/ui/circulation/column-chart/circulation-column-charts/circulation-column-charts.component.spec.ts:53:17
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:416:32)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:2176:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:415:38)
      at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
      at Object.wrappedFunc (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:450:38)

Test code:
import { Spectator, createComponentFactory } from "@ngneat/spectator/jest";
import { CirculationColumnChartsComponent } from "./circulation-column-charts.component";
import { BanknotesAndCoinsService } from "../../../../data-access/banknotes-and-coins.service";
import { CirculationColumnChartName } from "../../../../models/circulation-column-charts-visibility.type";
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { AsyncPipe } from "@angular/common";

import { TranslateModule, TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { LanguageService } from "../../../../../shared/data-access/language.service";
import { ChartsConfigurationHelperService } from "../../../../../shared/data-access/charts-configuration-helper/charts-configuration-helper.service";
import { provideHttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { provideHttpClientTesting } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { BanknotesAndCoinsClientService } from "../../../../data-access/banknotes-and-coins.client.service";
import { TranslateServiceStub } from "../../../../../../../tests/translation-service-stub";

describe("CirculationColumnChartsComponent", () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<CirculationColumnChartsComponent>;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    shallow: true,
    detectChanges: false,
    component: CirculationColumnChartsComponent,
    providers: [
      provideHttpClient(),
      provideHttpClientTesting(),
      {
        provide: BanknotesAndCoinsClientService,
        useValue: {},
      },
      {
        provide: BanknotesAndCoinsService,
        useValue: {
          circulationQuantitySeriesData$: jest.fn(() => true),
          circulationValueSeriesData$: jest.fn(() => true),
        },
      },
      { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceStub },
      { provide: LanguageService, useClass: {} },
      { provide: ChartsConfigurationHelperService, useClass: {} },
    ],
    imports: [HighchartsChartModule, AsyncPipe, TranslateModule],
  });

  beforeAll(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  const testsData = [
    {
      chartName: CirculationColumnChartName.BanknotesQuantityChart,
      testId: "banknotesQuantity_Chart",
    },
    {
      chartName: CirculationColumnChartName.CoinsQuantityChart,
      testId: "coinsQuantity_Chart",
    },
    {
      chartName: CirculationColumnChartName.BanknotesAndCoinsQuantityChart,
      testId: "banknotesAndCoinsQuantity_Chart",
    },
    {
      chartName: CirculationColumnChartName.BanknotesValueChart,
      testId: "banknotesValue_Chart",
    },
    {
      chartName: CirculationColumnChartName.CoinsValueChart,
      testId: "coinsValue_Chart",
    },
    {
      chartName: CirculationColumnChartName.BanknotesAndCoinsValueChart,
      testId: "banknotesAndCoinsValue_Chart",
    },
  ];

  test.each(testsData)("testName", (testData) => {
    spectator.setInput("whichChartToDisplay", testData.chartName);
    spectator.detectChanges();

    const chartElement = spectator.queryAll(
      `[data-test-id="${testData.testId}"]`,
    );
    console.log(chartElement);
    expect(chartElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

Code of component (not in its entirety, just the most important part with dependencies, etc.)
@Component({
  selector: "app-circulation-column-charts",
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HighchartsChartModule, AsyncPipe, TranslateModule],
  templateUrl: "./circulation-column-charts.component.html",
  styleUrl: "./circulation-column-charts.component.scss",
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CirculationColumnChartsComponent extends ExportableChartComponent {
  readonly HighchartsStock: typeof HighchartsStock = HighchartsStock;
  readonly chartConstructorType = "stockChart";
  readonly CirculationColumnChartName = CirculationColumnChartName;

  whichChartToDisplay = input.required<CirculationColumnChartName>();

  private banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData$ =
    this.banknotesAndCoinsService.circulationQuantitySeriesData$;
  private banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData$ =
    this.banknotesAndCoinsService.circulationValueSeriesData$;

  constructor(
    private chartsConfigurationService: ChartsConfigurationHelperService,
    private banknotesAndCoinsService: BanknotesAndCoinsService,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private languageService: LanguageService,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  chartsConfigs$ = this.languageService.languageChangedSuccess$.pipe(
    startWith(true),
    switchMap(() =>
      forkJoin({
        banknotesAndCoinsQuantityChartOptions:
          this.banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData$.pipe(
            map((banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData) =>
              this.getChartConfiguration(
                circulationSeriesConfig,
                banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData,
                Measure.Quantity,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        banknotesQuantityChartOptions:
          this.banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData$.pipe(
            map((banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData) =>
              this.getChartConfiguration(
                banknotesCirculationSeriesConfig,
                banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData,
                Measure.Quantity,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        coinsQuantityChartOptions:
          this.banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData$.pipe(
            map((banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData) =>
              this.getChartConfiguration(
                coinsCirculationSeriesConfig,
                banknotesAndCoinsQuantitySeriesData,
                Measure.Quantity,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        banknotesAndCoinsValueChartOptions:
          this.banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData$.pipe(
            map((banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData) =>
              this.getChartConfiguration(
                circulationSeriesConfig,
                banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData,
                Measure.Value,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        banknotesValueChartOptions: this.banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData$.pipe(
          map((banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData) =>
            this.getChartConfiguration(
              banknotesCirculationSeriesConfig,
              banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData,
              Measure.Value,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        coinsValueChartOptions: this.banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData$.pipe(
          map((banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData) =>
            this.getChartConfiguration(
              coinsCirculationSeriesConfig,
              banknotesAndCoinsValueSeriesData,
              Measure.Value,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      }),
    ),
  );
}


If I'm not mistaken you can simply remove the provideHttpClient and leave the other one in there?
